# SWIG C++ Python nested class

Tags: c++, python-3.x, swig, inner-classes

**upcast.h:**

```
namespace Upc{
    class Parent {
    public:
    Parent() {};
    ~Parent() {};
    class Child;
    };
    class Parent::Child : public Parent {
    public:
        Child() {};
    };

    class Test {
    public:
        Test(const double &i) {};
        Test(const Parent &p) {};

    };

}  //end of namespace Upc
```

**upcast.i:**

```
%module upcast 
%feature("flatnested");
%include <windows.i>
%{
# include "upcast.h"
%}
%include <upcast.h>
```

**in shell:**

```
from upcast import *
Test(Child())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upcast_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    Test(Child())
  File "D:\swigsimbody\dp64\x64\Release\upcast.py", line 146, in __init__
    this = _upcast.new_Test(*args)
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Test'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    Upc::Test::Test(double const &)
    Upc::Test::Test(Upc::Parent const &)
```

**Question:**

`Test(Parent())` works fine, I am wondering why the derived class Child object can't be used in the Test constructor.

Comment: If `Child` wasn't also inheriting from `Parent` you could use the old `%nestedworkaround`. If you really need a nested class inheriting from an outer class, you could consider exposing a cast function with signature, `Parent* Cast(Parent::Child* pChild)`. Not so elegant, but it works

Comment: for the second way, is there anyway I could maintain the derived class functionality after I cast it into the base class type?   Parent* 
    Cast(Parent::Child* pChild) {
      return pChild;
     };

Comment: You need to upcast to `Parent*` inside the Cast function. To access functionality which are not defined in the base class, you need to downcast